# GMap.Net .ToImage() Function Outputting Images With Blank Tiles

Tags: gmap.net

The `.ToImage()` function in GMap.Net does not appear to wait for the map data to be downloaded before the screenshot is taken. This results in images with blank tiles. Is there any existing capability that would allow GMaps to wait until the map is loaded?

I already posted my question on [GitHub](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/issues/113) but haven't gotten a response so far. So any help is appreciated.

**VB.NET Code**

```
Private Function TakeBitmapScreenShot() As Image
   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
   'Code to wait until all tiles have loaded
   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
   Return GMapControl.ToImage()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of the ways around this are using the TilePrefetcher or even better this [code](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/master/Demo.WindowsForms/Forms/StaticImage.cs).

Answer (score 1):

You can Handle the event (**OnTileLoadComplete** ) which fires when the tile images completly loaded and then you can take the screenshot

```
GMapControl1.OnTileLoadComplete += GMapControl1_OnTileLoadComplete;

private void GMapControl1_OnTileLoadComplete(long ElapsedMilliseconds)
{
    GMapControl.ToImage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it wasn't always working for some reason.